# Fetching value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

How can I fetch the world `'hello'` from the following dictionary structure in Python?

```
d = {
  'k1': [1, 2, 3, {
    'tricky': ['oh', 'man', 'inception', {
      'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: at least you could have say in which language ??

Comment: maybe `d['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]['target'][3]` ?

Comment: In python i am trying to solve this problem

Comment: then my above answer will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

`d['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]['target'][3]`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
In [1]: d['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]['target'][3]
Out[1]: 'hello'
```